# 802.1x, what is meant by "port-based"?

Tags: port, 802.1

I'm reading about 802.1X, mainly on Wikipedia, but can't quite get it. So here is a very basic question:

What is meant, when they say that 802.1X is "port-based"?

Comment: A "port", the place where the network wire physically plugs into the switch.

Comment: So it's all about physical wired ports. 802.11i (wpa2) uses 802.1X as it's access control mechanism. In that context 802.1x is suddenly not port-based at all, or what? That is what made me question my initial understanding.

Comment: See Jeff's comment to Lucas' answer. That solves it.

Comment: There was no WiFi when the standard was written... so yeah, WiFi changed things a bit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well as the standard says:

*"Port-based network access control makes use of the physical access characteristics of IEEE 802 LAN infrastructures in order to provide a means of authenticating and authorizing devices attached to a LAN port that has point-to-point connection characteristics, and of preventing access to that port in cases which the authentication and authorization fails. A port in this context is **a single point of attachment to the LAN infrastructure**."*

Comment: ... though that attachment may be a virtual port such as over a wifi connection. It doesn't have to be a direct hardware port.